# RecyclerView to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I actually want cardView in my RecyclerView  to retrieve data from firebase but it returns error. Please do help me to attach my RecyclerView to firebase and retrieve data from it. 
Thanking you in advance.

Here is the **mainActivity.java**

```
    mbloglist = findViewById(R.id.rv1);        
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    productAdapter adapter = new productAdapter(this);

    mbloglist.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mbloglist.setAdapter(adapter);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Layout starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    database1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database1.getReference("Users");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Database Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e("pppp","onDataChange"+dataSnapshot.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ModelClass modelClass = child.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                modelClassList.add(modelClass);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter.addItems(modelClassList);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("pppp","onCancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the Adapter which named **ProductAdapter.java**

```
 public productAdapter(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      this.productList = new ArrayList<>();
   }

public void addItems(List<ModelClass> productList){
    this.productList = productList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public productViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new productViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull productViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelClass modelClass = productList.get(position);
    holder.shop_name.setText(modelClass.getStore_name());
    holder.phone_number.setText(modelClass.getphone_number());
    holder.v7b.setText(modelClass.getV7b());
    holder.v7g.setText(modelClass.getV7g());
    holder.y53b.setText(modelClass.getY53b());
    holder.y53g.setText(modelClass.getY53g());
    holder.v7pb.setText(modelClass.getV7pb());
    holder.v7pg.setText(modelClass.getV7pg());
    holder.y55sb.setText(modelClass.getY55sb());
    holder.y55sg.setText(modelClass.getY55sb());
    holder.i3b.setText(modelClass.getI3b());
    holder.i3go.setText(modelClass.getI3go());
    holder.i3gr.setText(modelClass.getI3gr());
    holder.i3prob.setText(modelClass.getI3prob());
    holder.i3progo.setText(modelClass.getI3progo());
    holder.i3progr.setText(modelClass.getI3progr());
    holder.i5b.setText(modelClass.getI5b());
    holder.i5go.setText(modelClass.getI5go());
    holder.i5gr.setText(modelClass.getI5gr());
    holder.i5prob.setText(modelClass.getI5prob());
    holder.i5progo.setText(modelClass.getI5progo());
    holder.i5progr.setText(modelClass.getI5progr());
    holder.i7b.setText(modelClass.getI7b());
    holder.i7go.setText(modelClass.getI7go());
    holder.i7gr.setText(modelClass.getI7gr());
    holder.camonb.setText(modelClass.getCamonb());
    holder.camongo.setText(modelClass.getCamongo());
    holder.camonbl.setText(modelClass.getCamonbl());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class productViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView shop_name,phone_number,v7b,v7g,y53b,y53g,v7pb,v7pg,y55sb,y55sg,y69b,y69g,i3b,i3go,i3gr,i3prob,i3progo,i3progr,i5b,i5go,i5gr,i5prob,i5progo,i5progr,i7b,i7go,i7gr,camonb,camongo,camonbl;

    public productViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        shop_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText2000);
        phone_number=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText2001);
        v7b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText101);
        v7g=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText102);
        y53b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText103);
        y53g=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText104);
        v7pb=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText105);
        v7pg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText106);
        y55sb=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText107);
        y55sg=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText108);
        y69b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText109);
        y69g=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText110);
        i3b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText111);
        i3go=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText112);
        i3gr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText113);
        i3prob=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText114);
        i3progo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText115);
        i3progr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText116);
        i5b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText117);
        i5go=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText118);
        i5gr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText119);
        i5prob=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText120);
        i5progo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText121);
        i5progr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText122);
        i7b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText123);
        i7go=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText124);
        i7gr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText125);
        camonb=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText126);
        camongo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText127);
        camonbl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditText128);
```

Here is the **modelclass.java** which attached to firebase

```
public class ModelClass {
String v7b;
String v7g;
String y53b;
String y53g;
String v7pb;
String v7pg;
String y55sb;
String y55sg;
String y69b;
String y69g;
String i3b;
String i3go;
String i3gr;
String i3prob;
String i3progo;
String i3progr;
String i5b;
String i5go;
String i5gr;
String i5prob;
String i5progo;
String i5progr;
String i7b;
String i7go;
String i7gr;
String camonb;
String camongo;
String camonbl;
String email;
String store_name;
String phone_number;

public ModelClass() {

}

public ModelClass(String v7b, String v7g, String y53b, String y53g, String v7pb, String v7pg, String y55sb, String y55sg, String y69b, String y69g, String i3b, String i3go, String i3gr, String i3prob, String i3progo, String i3progr, String i5b, String i5go, String i5gr, String i5prob, String i5progo, String i5progr, String i7b, String i7go, String i7gr, String camonb, String camongo, String camongr) {
    this.v7b = v7b;
    this.v7g = v7g;
    this.y53b = y53b;
    this.y53g = y53g;
    this.v7pb = v7pb;
    this.v7pg = v7pg;
    this.y55sb = y55sb;
    this.y55sg = y55sg;
    this.y69b = y69b;
    this.y69g = y69g;
    this.i3b = i3b;
    this.i3go = i3go;
    this.i3gr = i3gr;
    this.i3prob = i3prob;
    this.i3progo = i3progo;
    this.i3progr = i3progr;
    this.i5b = i5b;
    this.i5go = i5go;
    this.i5gr = i5gr;
    this.i5prob = i5prob;
    this.i5progo = i5progo;
    this.i5progr = i5progr;
    this.i7b = i7b;
    this.i7go = i7go;
    this.i7gr = i7gr;
    this.camonb = camonb;
    this.camongo = camongo;
    this.camonbl = camongr;
}

public ModelClass(String email, String store_name, String phone_number) {
    this.email = email;
    this.store_name = store_name;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

String phone;

public String getV7b() {
    return v7b;
}

public void setV7b(String v7b) {
    this.v7b = v7b;
}

public String getV7g() {
    return v7g;
}

public void setV7g(String v7g) {
    this.v7g = v7g;
}

public String getY53b() {
    return y53b;
}

public void setY53b(String y53b) {this.y53b = y53b;}

public String getY53g() {
    return y53g;
}

public void setY53g(String y53g) {
    this.y53g = y53g;
}

public String getV7pb() {
    return v7pb;
}

public void setV7pb(String v7pb) {
    this.v7pb = v7pb;
}

public String getV7pg() {
    return v7pg;
}

public void setV7pg(String v7pg) {
    this.v7pg = v7pg;
}

public String getY55sb() {
    return y55sb;
}

public void setY55sb(String y55sb) {
    this.y55sb = y55sb;
}

public String getY55sg() {
    return y55sg;
}

public void setY55sg(String y55sg) {
    this.y55sg = y55sg;
}

public String getY69b() {
    return y69b;
}

public void setY69b(String y69b) {
    this.y69b = y69b;
}

public String getY69g() {
    return y69g;
}

public void setY69g(String y69g) {
    this.y69g = y69g;
}

public String getI3b() {
    return i3b;
}

public void setI3b(String i3b) {
    this.i3b = i3b;
}

public String getI3go() {
    return i3go;
}

public void setI3go(String i3go) {
    this.i3go = i3go;
}

public String getI3gr() {
    return i3gr;
}

public void setI3gr(String i3gr) {
    this.i3gr = i3gr;
}

public String getI3prob() {
    return i3prob;
}

public void setI3prob(String i3prob) {
    this.i3prob = i3prob;
}

public String getI3progo() {
    return i3progo;
}

public void setI3progo(String i3progo) {
    this.i3progo = i3progo;
}

public String getI3progr() {
    return i3progr;
}

public void setI3progr(String i3progr) {
    this.i3progr = i3progr;
}

public String getI5b() {
    return i5b;
}

public void setI5b(String i5b) {
    this.i5b = i5b;
}

public String getI5go() {
    return i5go;
}

public void setI5go(String i5go) {
    this.i5go = i5go;
}

public String getI5gr() {
    return i5gr;
}

public void setI5gr(String i5gr) {
    this.i5gr = i5gr;
}

public String getI5prob() {
    return i5prob;
}

public void setI5prob(String i5prob) {
    this.i5prob = i5prob;
}

public String getI5progo() {
    return i5progo;
}

public void setI5progo(String i5progo) {
    this.i5progo = i5progo;
}

public String getI5progr() {
    return i5progr;
}

public void setI5progr(String i5progr) {
    this.i5progr = i5progr;
}

public String getI7b() {
    return i7b;
}

public void setI7b(String i7b) {
    this.i7b = i7b;
}

public String getI7go() {
    return i7go;
}

public void setI7go(String i7go) {
    this.i7go = i7go;
}

public String getI7gr() {
    return i7gr;
}

public void setI7gr(String i7gr) {
    this.i7gr = i7gr;
}

public String getCamonb() {
    return camonb;
}

public void setCamonb(String camonb) {
    this.camonb = camonb;
}

public String getCamongo() {
    return camongo;
}

public void setCamongo(String camongo) {
    this.camongo = camongo;
}

public String getCamonbl() {
    return camonbl;
}

public void setCamongr(String camongr) {
    this.camonbl = camongr;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getStore_name() {
    return store_name;
}

public void setStorename(String storename) {this.store_name = storename;}

public String getphone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}

public void setphone_number(String phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
}
```

Here is the Firebase Realtime Database Image

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What are inside the element phone in firebase? and in the other user Is it the same structure?

Comment: 1 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alagappan.vivo, PID: 28084 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)

Comment: 2 at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source) at com.example.alagappan.vivo.Main23Activity$1.onDataChange(Main23Activity.java:58) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: 3 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: This are the elements in the database                                      camonb: 
"5"
 camonbl: 
"7"
 camongo: 
"6"
 i3b: 
"1"
 i3go: 
"2"
 i3gr: 
"3"
 i3prob: 
"4"
 i3progo: 
"5"
 i3progr: 
"6"
 i5b: 
"7"
 i5go: 
"8"
 i5gr: 
"9"
 i5prob: 
"10"
 i5progo: 
"0"
 i5progr: 
"1"
 i7b: 
"2"
 i7go: 
"3"
 i7gr: 
"4"
 v7b: 
"1"
 v7g: 
"10"
 v7pb: 
"1"
 v7pg: 
"5"
 y53b: 
"1"
 y53g: 
"2"
 y55sb: 
"1"
 y55sg: 
"6"
 y69b: 
"9"
 y69g: 
"10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelClass class and your database doesn't have the same structure, because in your database you have a new node called "phone" inside each userID node.

You can try 3 approaches to solve this issue:

a.) Write data in your database just like ModelClass is, without "phone" node.

b.) Create a new class called "Phone" with same attributes you have inside "phone" node in the database, and make this new class part of ModelClass class.

c.) On myRef onDataChange method, inside for statement, check for each child key and fill ModelClass atributes one by one. When the child key is equal to "phone", start a new loop statement in "phone" children to fill these attributes.

Comment: I have got correct output i tried 1st method and got corrected my mistake thank you @Ronaldo Zoccaratto de Souza

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}
```

Comment: E/pppp: onDataChangeDataSnapshot { key = Users, value = {7hGmVs9QfnaqAZQTFI5oTGVdzRA2={phone={i5go=8, y53g=2, i5prob=10, i7gr=4, i3b=1, v7pb=1, i3progo=5, v7g=10, i5progo=0, i3go=2, i5gr=9, y69b=9, i3prob=4, i7b=2, y69g=10, i5b=7, y53b=1, v7b=1, i3gr=3, i3progr=6, v7pg=5, i5progr=1, camongo=6, camonb=5, i7go=3, camonbl=7, y55sb=1, y55sg=6}, email=alagappa2@gmail.com, store_name=abc, phone_number=9999999999}, htG7VeSfqdYDa8DPy2B7C10sIsm1={phone={y53b=1, y53g=1}, email=viswa.2511@gmail.com, store_name=az, phone_number=8556843685}} }

Comment: in logcats it gets the value and it shows that unfortunately stopped the application and gets the error as such

Comment: 1      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alagappan.vivo, PID: 28084
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)

Comment: 2    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.example.alagappan.vivo.Main23Activity$1.onDataChange(Main23Activity.java:58)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: 3  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: I have separated the errors which is on logcat and separated it as 1 2 and 3 please do help me @nitish29 brother

Comment: public static class ModelClass  , use this and try

Comment: OK let me try it brother